# How to return unique list of text pivot by Query

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to mimic a pivot table behaviour where you would grab all distinct values from Col B and, by each of those unique Col B values, you associate all each respective values, that must also be distinct by each unique Col B.

Here's my data set:

```
A               B
y_13_other  4601032322-video
y_13_other  4601032322-video
o_06_other  4601032322-video1
o_06_other  4601032322-video
o_06_other  4601032322-video2
```

The final result should be:

```
 B                   A
4601032322-video   y_13_other
4601032322-video   o_06_other
4601032322-video1  o_06_other
4601032322-video2  o_06_other
```

I've tried the query with `Group by`, but it doesn't seem possible to aggregate by text.

```
=QUERY(A2:B5;"SELECT A,B group by B")
```

This would need an AGG, and it only seems to work with numbers.

Another option I thought was to pair a query with `vlookup`, but I haven't managed to, is there a way to do this, even without the query formula?

Note: I don't know how many rows A or B is going to have and don't know their future names, it would have to work dynamically.

[image: Pivot Table example]

Comment: you can use double query and agg with count then drop the coun column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY({A1:B}, 
 "select Col1, Col2, 
  count(Col2) 
  group by Col1, Col2", 0),
 "select Col2, Col1 
  where Col1 is not NULL 
  order by Col2", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly! But is there any other way to do it? It feels like there must be a different way